# Logical condition when declaring handler procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql-5.6, error-handling, development

I have a procedure in MySQL that executes a handler for `SQLEXCEPTION` to read the errno code and insert it to a table.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
@errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
```

I'm expecting something like this

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION OR SQLWARNING
BEGIN
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
@errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
```

Is there a chance to use `OR` or `AND` logical operators in sql handler?

Or, can I get some advice to get the `WARNING` and `ERROR` messages in one `DECLARE` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the Mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/handler-scope.html you can create a handler with two handlers and the same scope, be aware of the precedence

Example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p1()
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42S02'
    SELECT 'SQLSTATE handler was activated' AS msg;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    SELECT 'SQLEXCEPTION handler was activated' AS msg;

  DROP TABLE test.t;
END;
```